# do while statement to check two conditions

Tags: java, do-while

I have written a Java code as below, which generates random numbers and sums them to give correct answer. However, I am also trying to generate to two false answers that are not equal to each other or the correct answer using do while statement. However, it is not working. The last do part of the java code is not being run. It is possible to have two random number ans_wrong1 and ans_wrong2 which are the same.

In simple english, if ans_wrong2 equals ans_wrong1 OR ans_correct, generate another random number. Continue this process until number is generated which is not equal to any of the other two numbers. Can someone spot what I am doing wrong and offer suggestion?

Lets try to simplify the question further, because, the suggested solutions are not working.

I want t generate two random numbers that do not equal to each other or the correct answer.

Code updated - still not working

Thanks

```
int ans_correct = 8;

int ans_wrong1;
    do {
        ans_wrong1 = randomGenerator.nextInt(20);
    } while(ans_wrong1 == ans_correct);

    int ans_wrong2;
    do {
        ans_wrong2 = randomGenerator.nextInt(10);
    } while ( ans_wrong2 == ans_correct || ans_wrong2 == ans_wrong1 );
```

Comment: Can you explain why it is not working?

Comment: shouldn't you test whether `ans_wrong2` neither equals `ans_wrong1` nor àns_correct` in the final loop ? if you'd do so, the second but last loop could be eliminated.

Comment: As per your logic, and_correct will be = ans_wrong1 and and_wrong2.. And I guess you don't want them to be equal.. Right?

Comment: ans_wrong1 should not equal to ans_correct. ans_wrong2 should not equal to ans_correct and ans_wrong1.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that first you generate a number that is not equal to `ans_correct`, and then you throw it away, and generate a new one which is not equal to `ans_wrong1`, without even looking at `ans_correct`.

To do what you want, you need to generate a number, and then test it for *both* conditions at the same time:

```
do {
    ans_wrong2 = randomGenerator.nextInt(10);
} while ( ans_wrong2 == ans_correct || ans_wrong2 == ans_wrong1 );
```

Comment: is there a limit to how many conditions I can impose on using the above command

Comment: Yes, if you compare to 10 different numbers in the same range (0-9), this will become an endless loop, because there is no way to generate another number between 0 and 9 that is different than all of them.

Comment: I ran the programme with your suggestion. I got the following response. 12   8  8. >:-( I am still not getting three unique numbers.

Comment: Show the updated version of the program (edit your question and add it) - perhaps you didn't add it in the correct place. Make sure you also show the printing.

Comment: I have updated the question with latest code which gave me the answer 12  8  8.

Comment: @Learningmind you forgot to add the part of the code that prints it. I'm not sure even where you got that 12. Shouldn't it be printing the correct answer first? In short, show whole code.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has a couple of bugs... firstly, what you already know:

### Value Overwrite

Your code blocks may unintentionally undo each other:

> ```
> int ans_wrong2;
> do {
>     ans_wrong2 = randomGenerator.nextInt(10);
>
> } while(ans_wrong2 == ans_correct);
>
> do {
>     ans_wrong2 = randomGenerator.nextInt(10);
> } while(ans_wrong2 == ans_wrong1);
> ```

The second while loop will replace the ans_wrong value always, and it may replace it with the value that was excluded in the first loop (i.e. the second loop may produce `ans_correct`.

The simple solution to this would be:

```
int ans_wrong2;
do {
    ans_wrong2 = randomGenerator.nextInt(10);

} while(ans_wrong2 == ans_correct || ans_wrong2 == ans_wrong1);
```

### Impossible Answers

The second bug is that your ans_correct can never be the value 9. This is because `randomGenerator.nextInt(5)` will always return a value from 0 to 4.

Adding two of them together, will produce a value from 0 to 8.

randomGenerator.nextInt(10), however, will possibly produce the value 9.... which would never be an option.

### Code Example:

```
private static final Random randomGenerator = new Random();

public static final void testRand() {
    int ans_correct = randomGenerator.nextInt(5) + randomGenerator.nextInt(5);

    int ans_wrong1;
    do {
        ans_wrong1 = randomGenerator.nextInt(10);
    } while(ans_wrong1 == ans_correct);

    int ans_wrong2;
    do {
        ans_wrong2 = randomGenerator.nextInt(10);

    } while(ans_wrong2 == ans_correct);

    do {
        ans_wrong2 = randomGenerator.nextInt(10);
    } while(ans_wrong2 == ans_wrong1);

    System.out.printf("Correct %d  WA1 %d WA2 %d\n", ans_correct, ans_wrong1, ans_wrong2);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        testRand();
    }
}
```

[**working at Ideone**](https://ideone.com/uyad0e)

Comment: I have updated the code in my question. It is still not generating unique numbers. Maybe I am trying to do something that cannot be done in java.

Comment: There is nothing wrong any more with the code in your question, what's probably wrong is the code you use to print the results.

Comment: I am using simple print line. I got excited initially when the three numbers were all different but after running the programme few times, two numbers turned out to be the same. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine.In your code the 2nd do while loop is having no effect as the value of ans_wrong2 is anyhow getting replaced in the 3rd loop and in the last loop you are only checking if it's equal to ans_wrong1. Thus there's still a chance that it may be equal to ans_correct.

```
Random randomGenerator = new Random();

int random1 = randomGenerator.nextInt(5);
int random2 = randomGenerator.nextInt(5);

int ans_correct = random1 + random2;

int ans_wrong1;
do {
    ans_wrong1 = randomGenerator.nextInt(10);
} while(ans_wrong1 == ans_correct);

int ans_wrong2;
do {
    ans_wrong2 = randomGenerator.nextInt(10);

} while(ans_wrong2 == ans_correct || ans_wrong2 == ans_wrong1);
```